# Change starting gold or allowed turns of a campaign scenario

Tags: battle-for-wesnoth

I am playing the campaign "Heir to the Throne" and would love to play the first scenario, "The Elves Besieged", with more starting gold and allowed turns. I would enjoy this especially since this map is so well-suited for elves.

I know there is documentation about how to create scenarios and campaigns. However I would greatly appreciate any pointers or steps to take (like "open file xyz, edit line 42") as that would save me a lot of reading.

Answer (score 2):

ok, I found it out.
Scenario file is a simple text file in the game data directory under "data/campaigns/Heir_To_The_Throne/01_The_Elves_Besieged.cfg". Turns are defined at line 8, starting gold at line 76 (as of Wesnoth version 1.12). I tried it, it works.

two words of warning:

- This is essentially cheating. It might spoil the game for you. Think about, if this is really what yout want to do.
- You might want to make a backup of the file(s) that you are going to edit.